# $S=\{1\le a \le n:(a,n)=1,a^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n\}$, $T=\{1\le b \le n:(b,n)=1,b^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n\}$ iwth composite and prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography, primality-test

I have two sets with $n>2$ natural number:

$S=\{1\le a \le n:(a,n)=1,a^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n\}$

$T=\{1\le b \le n:(b,n)=1,b^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n\}$

Can anyone explain me if there are prime numbers $n$ for whom $S\neq\emptyset$?and are there any composite numbers $n$ for whom $S=\emptyset$? I think that i have to apply an primality test but i do not know what.
Also how i can prove this:
Also how to  prove:  if $S\neq\emptyset$ show that $|S|\geφ(n)/2$ without knowing anything for $φ(n)$

Comment: The answer to the first question is No by using Fermat's Little Theorem. For the second question, look up charmicheal numbers.

Comment: how i can show the first ?

Comment: i think that the fisrt question can be answered by Fermat primality test but i got stuck on how to apply it